# What is the best way to find the roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Calculus, mainly when we compute areas we face equations like

$$x^\frac{1}{2}=x^2$$

I know that I can take the square root of the both sides. Does anyone know another way to find the roots of the equation?

Comment: Since this question is unrelated to [tag:calculus] and [tag:definite-integrals] I've replaced the tags with [tag:algebra-precalculus].

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{align} x^{1/2} = x^2 & \iff x^{1/2}(1-x^{3/2}) = 0\\ \\  & \iff x^{1/2} = 0, \quad \text{or}\quad x^{3/2} = 1 \\ \\ & \iff \quad  x = 0\quad \text{or}\quad x = 1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are dealing with Real Calculus, we need $x\ge0$

let $\displaystyle\sqrt x=y(\ge0)\implies x=y^2\implies y=y^4\iff y(y^3-1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then
\begin{align}
x^{\frac{1}{2}}&=\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^4\\
y&=y^4\\
y^4-y&=0\\
y(y^3-1)&=0\\
y(y-1)(y^2+y+1)&=0
\end{align}
For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, only $y_1=0$ and $y_2=1$ are the real roots. Hence $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$.